# How to validation kendo ui dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I having a problem validating Kendo dropdownlist if the user select "Please select" option. Please let me how i can trigger the validation

Here is the code that i have so far:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConsumerGenderID)
                        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                                .Name("Gender")
                                .HtmlAttributes(new { @Style = "align:center; font-size:12px; width:208px; length:35px" })
                                .OptionLabel("Please Select")
                                .Value("-1")
                                .DataTextField("OptionName")
                                .DataValueField("OptionID")
                                .DataSource(source =>
                                {
                                    source.Read(read =>
                                    {
                                        read.Action("GetGenderStatus", "ConsumerDetails");
                                    });
                                })

                        )
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GivenName1, " ")


                </div>
```

**Model**

```
Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a gender")]
        [UIHint("GridForeignKey")]
        [DisplayName("Gender")]
        public int ConsumerGenderID { get; set; }
        public string ConsumerGenderName { get; set;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try matching the names of the two fields.  eg "Gender" and GivenName1 are not equivalent so that right there would be enough to keep the validation from firing even if it weren't a kendo dropdown.

Perhaps try to use dropdownfor so it's a little easier to keep track of.

```
@Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m=>m.GivenName1)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.GivenName1)
```